# select query on with relations is not giving the results in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
records = Student::with(array('Mark' => function($marks)
    {
    $marks->select(DB::raw('sum(obtain_marks)'))->with(array('Subject' => function($subject){
    $subject->orderby('subject_name')->select(DB::raw('count(subjects.id)','sum(total_marks)','subject_name'));
        }));
    }))->where('id', $id)->get();
```

Why this is not executing?

its working in mysql
select count(subjects.id),sum(subjects.total_marks),sum(marks.obtain_marks),subjects.subject_name from students inner join marks on students.id = marks.student_id inner join subjects on subjects.id = marks.subject_id where students.id = 20 group by subjects.subject_name;  its working in mysql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Select you must select the column where you have local key

```
$records = Student::with(['Mark' => function($marks){
    $marks->select(DB::raw('sum(obtain_marks)'), 'Subject_id' /* same Problem here ->select('subject_id')*/)->with(['Subject' => function($subject){
        $subject->orderby('subject_name')
                ->select(DB::raw('count(subjects.id)','sum(total_marks)','subject_name'));
    }]);
}])
->where('id', $id)
->select('Mark_id') // you must select foreign key column to use relationship
->get();
```

Comment: but I don't know name of your database columns where foreign keys are attached

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir do you have same problem or what?

Comment: I'm asking to check whether this question can be resolved or the OP still needs help.